# Access MySQL server from Grails

Tags: mysql, grails

I like to setup a dedicated MySQL server in a LAN accessible from other computers of this network. How can I setup the database server and the clients?
How can a Grails application can access the MySQL from the same LAN?

Answer (score 1):

If your MySQL server is going to run on Windows then you can configure it with the installation program. For example, I downloaded the install file `mysql-installer-community-5.6.20.0.msi` (versions change quickly) and it offers the option of installing just the server:

[image]

Just follow the screen prompts and take all the default values (strongly recommended). The main values to remember are:

- The default network port number `3306`.
- The server's `ip address`.
- The `username`(s) and `password`(s) that you created that have access to
  MySQL.

Then I suggest you download HeidiSQL and configure a connection to your new MySQL server, that way you can manage your database server remotely:

[image]

Hope that helps.

Comment: Many thanks for the clear and practical answer. The setting is different. The MySQL server runs on Linux and the client runs either on Windows or on Linux. Could you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

You are asking 2 differents questions.

To set up mysql connection in your grails app, did you at least try to read the doc ?

http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#dataSource

It's just a jdbc connection string :

https://www.google.fr/?gws_rd=ssl#q=jdbc+mysql+connection+string+example

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know how to configure grails DataSource.groovy when mysql is in the localhost. That I am asking is 'what have I to do when the mysql is running on another computer". Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: yes, read the doc. As I said, it's just a jdbc connection string. Click on you mouse left button on my second link

Comment: In the file **DataSource.groovy** you need to change the variable `url` so it looks something like this: `url = "jdbc:mysql://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3306/yyyyyy"` (Replace xxx with your server's ip address and yyyyyy with your database name)

Comment: Salvador, I did it and I got "ERROR pool.ConnectionPool  - Unable to create initial connections of pool". Is something I have to do in the MySQL server side?

Comment: Usually the ConnectionPool is the first thing that tries to open a connection to the database. So it is very possible that the database is not accessible to your application server (i.e. Tomcat running Grails). Look into how to setup a "LAMP" server (many references on google) and just focus on the "M" (MySQL) part of the tutorials. Keep in mind that MySQL is installed by default in many Linux distributions, you probably just have to activate it.

Answer (score 0):

It's more than just the JDBC connect string. You won't get far without a driver, so uncomment the sample entry in `BuildConfig.groovy` in the `dependencies` section and update the version to the most recent:

```
dependencies {
   ...
   runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.34'
}
```

Set the `driverClassName` in `DataSource.groovy`, along with the correct JDBC `url` for your database. Replace `<server>` with the server name or IP address, and `<dbname>` with the correct database name. You will likely also want to add parameters at the end of the url in the querystring. And if the port is non-standard (3306 is the default) then add that in also. To ensure that you use INNODB tables (older versions of MySQL default to MyISAM), specify the `MySQL5InnoDBDialect` (or a subclass):

```
dataSource {
   ...
   driverClassName = 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'
   dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
   url = 'jdbc:mysql://<server>/<dbname>'
}
```

Run `grails compile` to download the driver jar and setup the classpath.

Comment: Do I have to setup properly the mysql server to allow remote access?

Comment: Yes, the bind address and port have to be configured correctly, and you need one or more `grant` calls to specify the single client IP address or a wildcard. If the web and db server are on the same box, you often run something like `grant all on <dbname>.* to <username>@localhost identified by '<password>'` but to allow non-localhost access you need a different or extra grants. This is readily available information - do a web search for `mysql remote access`